# populate datagridview according to selected row in another datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagrid

I have two datagrid gridproperty and gridpropertyselection. There is one table which contains data. i have to papulate data in datagridviw named gridpropertyselection accoring to selected row in gridProperty datagrid.

I want to which event will be for for this. i trid the following code . but getting error in  Dim index As Integer = gridProperty.CurrentRow.Index this line

```
    Private Sub gridProperty_SelectionChanged(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs) Handles gridProperty.RowStateChanged


    Dim dtPropertySelection As DataTable = m_ds.Tables(0)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim count As Integer = gridPropertySelection.Rows.Count
    '  If (gridProperty.CurrentRow.IsNewRow IsNot Nothing) Then
    Dim index As Integer = gridProperty.CurrentRow.Index
    Dim PropertyID As Integer = gridProperty.Rows(index).Cells("PropertyID").Value
    While i < dtPropertySelection.Rows.Count
        If PropertyID = dtPropertySelection.Rows(i).Item("PropertyID") Then
            gridPropertySelection.Rows.Add()
            gridPropertySelection.Rows(count).Cells("colSelectionDescription").Value() = dtPropertySelection.Rows(i).Item("SelectionDescription")
            gridPropertySelection.Rows(count).Cells("colAssociatedText").Value() = dtPropertySelection.Rows(i).Item("AssociatedText")
            count = count + 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
    End While
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CellClick event of the datagridview.
Also, try to use 
`Dim index As Integer = gridProperty.CurrentCell.RowIndex()`

Comment: got the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" by using Dim index As Integer = gridProperty.CurrentCell.RowIndex() line also

Comment: is there any data on your `gridProperty` ? Also, try changing the event to CellClick instead of selection changed.

Comment: If i am using cellclick event then default row which is selected , data is not populating in another datagrid at the time of form loading

Comment: yes there is data in gridProperty datagrid. I have to populate data in gridPropertySelection datagrid when propertyID is similar in gridProperty datagrid and the table from which i have to load data in gridPropertySelection

Comment: is the error still showing? Sorry for the late reply.Weird, I tried the code I posted and it works.